# How to destroy a pygubu window after app.run()?

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy, pygubu

I am starting to make something (IDK yet) using python and pygubu. To start of I have been exploring what you can do with pygubu. I have met an issue however that I have no idea how to solve. My problem is that I cannot destroy a window. I have tried:

```
import time
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk
import pygubu

def func():
    time.sleep(2.8)
    app.destroy()


class HelloWorldApp:
    global app

    def __init__(self):

        #1: Create a builder
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()

        #2: Load an ui file
        builder.add_from_file('IDKyet.ui')

        #3: Create the mainwindow
        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('window')

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = HelloWorldApp()
    app.run()
    func()
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tom\Documents\python\In development\I Do Not Know (yet).py", line 42, in <module>
    func()
  File "C:\Users\tom\Documents\python\In development\I Do Not Know (yet).py", line 11, in func
    app.destroy()
AttributeError: 'HelloWorldApp' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

So then I tried:

```
import time
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk
import pygubu

def func():
    time.sleep(2.8)
    window.destroy()

class HelloWorldApp:
    global window

    def __init__(self):

        #1: Create a builder
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()

        #2: Load an ui file
        builder.add_from_file('IDKyet.ui')

        #3: Create the mainwindow
        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('window')

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = HelloWorldApp()
    app.run()
    func()
```

Basically I have changed the global variable to being called `window` which is my parent window and I have referred to the window being destroyed as `window`. However I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tom\Documents\python\In development\I Do Not Know (yet).py", line 42, in <module>
    func()
  File "C:\Users\tom\Documents\python\In development\I Do Not Know (yet).py", line 11, in func
    window.destroy()
NameError: name 'window' is not defined
```

Even though I have made `window` a global variable. I am new to pygubu and need all the help I can get.
**How do you destroy a window using pygubu?** *NOTE:* *The error appears after closing the window.*
I would appreciate any help. [I tried this link but it doesn't help](https://libraries.io/pypi/pygubu).

Edit:

Now I know that after `app.run()` the window stops working/closes but how do you make it disappear (like the tkinter `destroy()` function)?

Comment: Why do you want to destroy the window after `app.run()` because the tkinter root window  has been destroyed after `app.run()`?  BTW, you can use `self.mainwindow.master.destroy()` inside `HelloWorldApp` class.

Comment: I don't quite understand @acw1668 . Basically I am just testing that I can close the window for future programs so I can have a command that ends the program by destroying the window.

Comment: Since `app.run()` is actually calling `tkinter.mainloop()`, the function will return only when the tkinter root window is destroyed.  That means after `app.run()`, the tkinter root window has been destroyed.  So why do you want to destroy an already destroyed window?

Comment: The window does not disappear though @acw1668 - so that is my issue

Comment: Add, before `app.run()`, `app.after(2800, window.destroy)`

Comment: Answer and then i'll upvote and accept @stovfl

Comment: Feel free to write a community answer, checkbox lower right, by your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to the comment by [@stovfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7414759/stovfl).**

> Add, before `app.run()`, `app.after(2800, window.destroy)`

This means that I can edit my code and it will work:

```
import time
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk
import pygubu



class HelloWorldApp:
    global window

    def __init__(self):

        #1: Create a builder
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()

        #2: Load an ui file
        builder.add_from_file('IDKyet.ui')

        #3: Create the mainwindow
        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('window')

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = HelloWorldApp()
    app.after(2800, window.destroy)
    app.run()
```